# How to run firebase on server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, server

I want to use firebase as a database service to my server to which a android app would send requests to. I want the server to retrieve data rather than the android app because I want to do some processing before sending data back to client (app).

My node code (index.js) :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var port = process.env.PORT || 10000

firebase = require('./firebase') // I added this cuz I can't use <script> tag here

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSynotgonnatell2Q-kwk85XrCyNnc",
    authDomain: "hnotgonnatell.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://hnotgonnatell.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "notgonnatell",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "699935506077"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database()

ref = database.ref("some_table")

data = {
    name : "my name",
    number : "2938019283"
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    ref.push(data)
    res.send("hello")
})

app.listen(port)
```

I cannot use `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>` cause I'm not connecting to firebase from client. So I instead copied the code from https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js and imported it into my index.js using `require()` . When I run the index.js I get:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
         ^

TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\workspace_javascript\firebase_try\index.js:24:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:422:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:143:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:537:3
```

It works well when I run it by returning a html with firebase code inside `<script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access Firebase products on a server, you should be using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), not the client SDK.

Answer (score 5):

1. Install firebase from NPM

   ```
     npm install --save firebase-admin
   ```
2. Initiallize firebase

   ```
     var admin = require('firebase-admin');

     var serviceAccount = require('path/to/serviceAccountKey.json');

     admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
       databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
     });
   ```

src: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Comment: You typically use the Firebase Admin SDK to access Firebase products from the server, not the client SDK as you're showing here.

Comment: That's my bad... fixed